# Inserting 'PTO' (please turn over)

Tags: page-breaking

Is there a way to create a command which is like a `\pagebreak` (in that it suggests that it might be a good place to break a page, but certainly doesn't enforce it) but which inserts 'PTO' ("please turn over") near the bottom of the first page?

[The context is that I have computer-generated material in which there are, roughly speaking, many pairs of 'headers' and associated 'pictures'. Sometimes the pictures are so large that they have to go on a page of their own. The PTO would indicate that this has happened, and so one could distinguish a header-with-picture from a header-without-picture (which occasionally occurs).]

Comment: The `turnthepage` package prints PTO-equivalent text.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen Please turn your comment into an answer, so that it can be upvoted and possibly (here: rather likely) be accepted.

Comment: @lockstep Sorry. I don't post any questions or answers any more in TeX-XS; just comments.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen `:-(`

Comment: @HarishKumar :-)

Comment: @MarcvanDongen any reason for it.

Comment: @texenthusiast It's a policy aimed at reducing meta-questions about questions and answers.

Comment: Isn't this question a duplicate of this one? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/239705/34551 (or, actually, the other way around?)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `turnthepage` package does what you want (as Marc van Dongen commented). You'll probably want to change the text though:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,turnthepage}
\renewcommand{\turnthepage}{\itshape Please turn over...}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Resulting in:

[image: pto]

Consult [the documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/turnthepage/doc/pdf/turnthepage.pdf) for package options and other features.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, what if at the last page I would like to indicate that this is the "End Page"?

Comment: `! LaTeX Error: Unknown option ` ' for package `turnpageetex'.`