# Writing on the last line of a page

Tags: spacing

I would like to put a phrase like "turn the page" or something on the bottom of a page, preferably on the last line. I may use `\vspace{ }` with some trial and error. I was wondering if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is what package [`turnthepage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/turnthepage) is for.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[english]{turnthepage}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Available options are `short` which writes `/...`, `english`, `francais`, `nederlands` and `deutsch`. One of these options must be selected but afterthat you can customize the message with

```
\renewcommand{\turnthepage}{<whatever you want>}
```

Comment: Is the any way to customize where this indication will be printed?

Answer (score 5):

Use `\vfill` command before the text. It places the text in the very end of the page.

Comment: If there is not enough space the text will spill on to the next page.  You will need to prevent a page break after the `\vfill` command somehow.